# Find if MsWord is installed on IOS phone

Tags: c#, ios, .net-maui, multiplatform

I am writing a multi-platform App using Net Maui.
The app may produce an MsWord file if requested by the user.
I know how to check if MsWord is installed on most OSes, except in IOS.
How do I find out if MsWord is installed on IOS?

I cannot find any information on this problem.

Answer (score 4):

The official Microsoft deeplink docs can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/integration/integrate-with-office-from-ios-applications)

| Application | Protocol |
| --- | --- |
| Excel | ms-excel: |
| OneNote | onenote: |
| PowerPoint | ms-powerpoint: |
| Word | ms-word: |

**Here is a link on how to open other iOS apps in Net Maui** [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/launcher?tabs=ios)

```
bool supportsUri = await Launcher.Default.CanOpenAsync("ms-word://");
```

Apple requires that you define the schemes you want to use. Add the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key and schemes to the Platforms/iOS/Info.plist and Platforms/MacCatalyst/Info.plist files:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>ms-word</string>  
</array>
```

The  elements are the URI schemes preregistered with your app. You can't use schemes outside of this list.

```
if (supportsUri)
    await Launcher.Default.OpenAsync("ms-word://someFileName");
```

**Below is an example of how how it's done natively.**

Add the url schemes into your Info.plist:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>ms-word</string>
</array>
```

And then in your code you can check to see if the app is installed and launch the app:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "ms-word://") else { return }
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```